# Passing 1st drop box value to 2nd drop box when 1st is selected

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How do I pass selected element to another drop box when for example I select Aitem from database table 'table1' which id is 1 and then 2nd drop box displays items where table2 has Aitem ID?

```
<tr>
<td>Markė</td>

<td><?php
include_once('inc\connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM marke";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='marke' id='a5'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['marke'] ."'>" . $row['marke'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?></td>
</tr> 

<tr>
<td>Modelis</td>
<td><?php
include_once('inc\connect.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM modelis WHERE marke_id = $marke";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='modelis' id='a6'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['modelis'] ."'>" . $row   ['modelis'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?></td></td>
```

Comment: you want this to happen on the same page?

Comment: yes exactly. without buttons, its like a registration form. you select on first drop box AUDI, then 2nd drop box gives u models A5, A6, 80, 100

Comment: you need ajax for that. there are plenty of php + ajax tutorials out there.

Comment: which one I cant find any that would pass dropbox variable to another dropbox variable when 1st dropbox variable is seleced

Comment: all that could be done with javascript

Comment: how could it be done? can u give an example?

Comment: it's hard to find / create an example that fits exactly what you need. you need to break down your problem into smaller sub-problems like calling a function when select changes, getting value of selected option, running an ajax query, setting value of selected option, etc. then try solve the sub-problems, and i'm sure all these smaller questions have been answered on SO already